# How to multiply rows for a column that contains negative and zero values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, case

I'm trying to get the Product of all rows for a specific column in a grouped by query.  Most examples I've found point me towards combining `exp`, `sum` and `log`

```
exp(sum(log([Column A])))
```

The problem I'm having is that the column contains some zeros for values and thus I'm getting this error when zeros get passed to the `log` function:

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

I thought I could work around this by using a `case` expression, but that just doesn't work the way I would think it should, as it seems to evaluate all cases...

```
select 
  Name,
  Product = case 
    when min([Value]) = 0 then 0 
    when min([Value]) <> 0 then exp(sum(log(I))) -- trying to get the product of all rows in this column
  end
 from ids
 group by Name
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e18f/1)

Given the following result set:

```
Id  Name  Value
_________________________________
1   a     1
2   a     2
3   b     0
4   b     1
```

I would expect to get the following rows:

```
Name  Product
_____________
a     2
b     0
```

So in summary...
How do you multiply rows in a column that can contain negative or zero valued numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The magic of [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) seems to do the trick for the test case in your question. Since you used a different example than in your SQL Fiddle, I don't know if that's what you want there too.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ids
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Value INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(3)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Ids ( Name, Value )
VALUES ( 'a', 1 );
INSERT INTO dbo.Ids ( Name, Value )
VALUES ( 'a', 2 );
INSERT INTO dbo.Ids ( Name, Value )
VALUES ( 'b', 0 );
INSERT INTO dbo.Ids ( Name, Value )
VALUES ( 'b', 1 );

SELECT   Name,
         CASE WHEN MIN(Value) = 0 THEN 0
              WHEN MIN(Value) > 0 THEN EXP(SUM(LOG(NULLIF(Value, 0)))) -- trying to get the product of all rows in this column
         END AS Product
FROM     Ids
GROUP BY Name;
```

Returns:

```
Name    Product
a       2
b       0
```

---

If you need a more general solution that handles negative numbers and other edge cases, see for example [The Product Aggregate in T-SQL Versus the CLR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548395/The-Product-Aggregate-in-T-SQL-Versus-the-CLR) by Scott Burkow. One T-SQL construction from that article is:

```
EXP(SUM(LOG(NULLIF(ABS([Value]), 0))))
*
IIF(SUM(IIF([Value] = 0, 1, NULL)) > 0, 0, 1)
*
IIF(SUM(IIF([Value] < 0, 1, 0)) % 2 = 1, -1, 1)
```

---

As to why your original `CASE` expression did not work as expected, from the documentation for [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#remarks) (emphasis added):

> You should only depend on order of evaluation of the WHEN conditions for scalar expressions (including non-correlated sub-queries that return scalars), **not for aggregate expressions**.

Comment: Great answer~

One quick clarification - instead of `EXP(SUM(LOG(...`, this should be `EXP(SUM(LN(...`, correct?

`LOG` calculates a Base-10 Logarithm instead of `LN`, which calculates the natural log.

Comment: @chrisdurheim `LN` is not a valid function in SQL Server. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/mathematical-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: gotcha; I was working on Postgres; that explains the difference. Thank you!